# Is it possible to evaluate the integral $\int_\gamma z e^{z^2} dz$ withought the definition of Contour integration?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> What is the value of $$\int_\gamma z e^{z^2} dz$$ Where $\gamma:[0,\pi]\to\mathbb C$ is defined as $\gamma(t) = 1-e^{it}$

I tryed evaluating this integral by simpy using the fact that: $$\int_\gamma f=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$

But I wasn't able to do so.

My teacher asks us to evaluate a lot of integrals over a semi-circle, and I often notice that when he does so, the function we are integrating is way more complicated and convoluted than the others. To me, this makes me think that there is a way of computing these kinds of integrals without actually using the definition of Contour integral. How can this be calculated?

Comment: what is the antiderivative of $f(z)=ze^{z^2}$?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{d}{dz}e^{z^2}=2ze^{z^2}$$